# Animation Conflict

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edit - After testing, I discovered that only one elevator will animate. So if I walk into an elevator, the animation might not play on it, but it plays on another elevator. I noticed this by accident. I thought the animator would control the animation based upon which OnTriggerEnter2D I approached. Apparently, this caused the bug I'm experiencing.

How do I properly label the elevators so that only that elevator I'm at will run an animation?

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class Elevator : MonoBehaviour
 {
private GameObject door;

[SerializeField]
private Text uiTxt; // Elevator UI text element
[SerializeField]
private Image uiBg; // Elevator Background image
[SerializeField]
private Image uiFg; // Elevator Foreground image

private void Start()
{
    door = GameObject.FindWithTag("Elevator");
    door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorOpen", false);// Starts closed has to be TRUE to open
    door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorClose", false); // Starts closed has to be TRUE to re-close

    uiBg.enabled = false;
    uiFg.enabled = false;
    uiTxt.enabled = false;

}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorOpen", true);
        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorClose", false);

        uiBg.enabled = true;
        uiFg.enabled = true;
        uiTxt.enabled = true;

    }
}



private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorOpen", false);
        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorClose", true);

        uiBg.enabled = false;
        uiFg.enabled = false;
        uiTxt.enabled = false;

    }
    else {
        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorOpen", false);
        door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("doorClose", false);
    }
}
}
```

Here's a peek at the animator I have set up if it's helpful:
[image]

I have it set up to where the parameters are bool values. The door opens when doorOpen is true and doorClose is false. It will close when doorOpen is false and doorClose is true. However, it will do nothing if both values are false.

NOTE - I'm using Unity 2019.1 Beta

Comment: I am pretty sure it deals with `door = GameObject.FindWithTag("Elevator");`  since both scripts are probably getting the same gameObject...

Comment: @Eddge How do I go about separating them individually?

Comment: You can either attach this script to the elevator gameObject itself and just call getComponent on that object(You could also give the elevator the trigger as well) or you can use `[SerializeField]` and attach it to them in the inspector.

Comment: door = GetComponent<GameObject>(); This will separate them individually? Or will I need door.GetComponent<GameObject>(); ?

Comment: Every Monobehavior already has a reference to its GameObject so if this script is already attach to the elevator then remove your `GameObject door` completely and just use `Animator myAnim = getComponent<Animator>();` in your start and do all your setBool calls on that animator.

Comment: Ok, now that sounds very doable! I'm going to give that a try and if I have any issues, I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddge That worked like a charm! I'll be happy if you turned that into an answer so I can accept. Thank you very much!

Comment: Done, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the issue was `door = GameObject.FindWithTag("Elevator");`  this will return the first GameObject it finds with that tag, this is why when you hit the 2 different triggers the same door was animating for both.

After finding out this script was already on your elevator, there is no need for the GameObject door, since every MonoBehavior has a reference to its own GameObject, you can just create an Animator variable, and call GetComponent() like this:

```
public class Elevator : MonoBehavior 
{
    Animator myAnim;

    void Start()
    {
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myAnim.SetBool("doorOpen", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("doorClose", false);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            myAnim.SetBool("doorOpen", true);
            myAnim.SetBool("doorClose", false);

            uiBg.enabled = true;
            uiFg.enabled = true;
            uiTxt.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            myAnim.SetBool("doorOpen", false);
            myAnim.SetBool("doorClose", true);

            uiBg.enabled = false;
            uiFg.enabled = false;
            uiTxt.enabled = false;

        }
        else 
        {
            myAnim.SetBool("doorOpen", false);
            myAnim.SetBool("doorClose", false);
        }
    }
}
```